# UIButton button titles changes by itself on click of another button to its title

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, set

I have 12 buttons in my app.  The last button title changes by itself to the title of any other button I press.  So for example, if button 3's title was Joe, then the last button (`tag 12`) automatically changes to Joe (even though there is no code to change its title.  This is weird!

PS: I initially set up the title in my code:

```
func btnSetIcon(btnNumber: Int){

    println("In btnSetIcon btnNumber = \(btnNumber)")

    btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    detail1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable
    detail1.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Never

    switch btnNumber {
        case 1: btn.setTitle("BUCKET\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 2: btn.setTitle("SHOP\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 3: btn.setTitle("GROCERY\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 4: btn.setTitle("TO DO\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 5: btn.setTitle("NOTES\nTO SELF", forState: .Normal)
        case 6: btn.setTitle("SOS\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 7: btn.setTitle("PHONE\n#'s", forState: .Normal)
        case 8: btn.setTitle("EVENT\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 9: btn.setTitle("YOUR 1\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 10: btn.setTitle("YOUR 2\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 11: btn.setTitle("YOUR 3\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        case 12: btn.setTitle("YOUR 4\nLIST", forState: .Normal)
        default: btn.setTitle("✚", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the buttons?

Comment: Are you calling `btnSetIcon()` when a button is pressed?  If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the variable `btn` into `btnSetIcon()`, so it must be a property of your `viewController`.  `btn` was probably left set to the last button you added to your `viewController`, so when you call `btnSetIcon()`, that is the button that gets updated.

Perhaps you want to do something like this in `btnSetIcon()`:

```
if let btn = self.view.viewWithTag(btnNumber) as? UIButton {
    // update btn in here
}
```